# How to read the properties file from perl script

Tags: perl, file

I have written a perl script where I will be connecting to database, for which I'm using this statement

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost;mysql_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock",
    "root", "password", {'RaiseError' => 1});
```

As I don't  want any information to be hardcoded, I want to use properties file where I can list the above details (e.g.,  database, host, mysql_socket) and read the details of properties file from the script. How can I write the properties file and read the details from perl script?

Comment: As usual, for common tasks, [Task::Kensho has recommendations](https://metacpan.org/module/Task::Kensho#Config-Modules:-Task::Kensho::Config)

Comment: Either pm of `Config::Properties` or `Config::Simple` should work for you. Links: http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Config-Properties-1.75/lib/Config/Properties.pm http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/Config-Simple-4.59/Simple.pm

Comment: @Rudra, gave you an alternative example.

Answer (score 2):

I had issues using `perl-Config-Simple` and decided to use `Config::Properties` instead. If you are experiencing the same, then you can try the following.

Make sure you have the `Config::Properties` installed. The following are several examples of how to install from command line, depending on the OS you are using, you'll want to use the appropriate choice:

1. `cpan Config::Properties`
2. `cpan install Config::Properties`
3. `yum install perl-Config-Properties`

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Properties;

open my $cfh, '<', './foo.properties' or die "unable to open property file";
my $properties = Config::Properties->new();
$properties->load($cfh);
my $dbName = $properties->getProperty('database.name');
my $dbUser = $properties->getProperty('database.user');
```

The property file:

```
database.name=somedb
database.user=someuser
```

Once you have the values in the variables, put them into your connection string and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of CPAN modules that helps you to achieve this task.
I like [Config::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config::Simple), for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Simple;
...
my $cfg = new Config::Simple('myapp.ini');
my $user = $cfg->param('database.user');
my $connection_str = $cfg->param('database.connection');
#...
```

and the file `myapp.ini`:

```
[database]
connection="DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost;mysql_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
user=root
;...
```

You can install the module from the terminal/command prompt using:

```
cpan install Config::Simple
```

or

```
yum install perl-Config-Simple
```

Comment: Can't locate object method "new" via package "Config::Simple" (perhaps you forgot to load "Config::Simple"?)...I'm getting this error

Comment: @Vishu — So load Config::Simple. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Using-Perl-modules

Comment: @Quentin: I did this-use Config::Simple;

Comment: @Vishu Do you have it installed?

Comment: @TLP I can't have it installed. Any other alternate solution

Comment: Try to learn how to install CPAN modules in your system. It's very helpful the use of third party modules. If you don't have enough permissions to install, use local::lib (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local%3A%3Alib)

Comment: @Rundra, I edited MiguelPrz's answer to show what you might be missing. If you still have issues, please share your OS and version of perl you are using. Most likely the edit will show you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp;
if($ENV eq "Prod"){
#Prod Configurations
temp = "Prod";
}
else{
# Stage and Test Confgurations
temp = "Stage";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My brick and mortar solution, exports one value from a properties file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line;
foreach $line (<STDIN>) {
  chomp($line);
  if(my $match = $line =~ /^(.*)=(.*)$/){
    my $key = $1;
    my $value = $2;
    if ($ARGV[0] eq $key) {
      print "$value\n";
      exit 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl mykey < file.properties`